# Shell Script : Take filename as an argument and on a standard output display the contents of the file with line number prefixed to it

Tags: bash, unix, shell-script, bash-scripting

So, I'm new to shell scripting and I'm trying to write a shell script which takes filename(`.txt`) as an argument and displays the line number prefixed with each line on a standard output.

This is the script I've written after some research : -

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="$1"

nl -w2 -ba -s -d $'\n' filename
```

and getting following errors : -

```
nl: ''$'\n': No such file or directory
nl: filename: No such file or directory
```

My `.txt` file content is : -

```
This is first line.
This is second line.
This is third line.
```

and desired output is : -

```
1This is first line.
2This is second line.
3This is third line.
```

I'd also like some sort of error handling if the passed argument is not a file.

Comment: You need `$filename` when you use the variable

Comment: Not getting any error now, but the output I'm getting now is : -                                   
 1-dThis is first line.
 2-dThis is second line.
 3-dThis is third line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems with `nl -w2 -ba -s -d $'\n' filename`:

- `-s` requires an option-argument. In your code `-d` is interpreted as the option-argument for `-s`. I guess this was not your intention.

  If you want `-s` to take an empty string then provide an empty string: `-s ''`. Note by convention (2a [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html)) `-w2` is equivalent to `-w 2` and `-ba` is equivalent to `-b a`, but `-s''` would be seen by the tool like `-s` and not equivalent to `-s ''`. You need to use `-s ''` (or `-s ""`) to pass an empty string to `-s`.
- Per the above, your `-d` is interpreted as the option-argument for `-s`; therefore `-d` is not interpreted as an option.
- Therefore the newline (from the expansion of `$'\n'`) is not interpreted as an option-argument for `-d`. It is interpreted as a pathname and there is `No such file or directory`.
- `filename` is a literal string: `filename`. There is `No such file or directory`. You want `$filename` and [you want to double-quote it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618) (i.e. `"$filename"`, like you double-quoted `"$1"`).
- Consider [`--`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618) (if your `nl` supports it), in case `$filename` starts with `-`.

The fix:

```
nl -w 2 -b a -s '' -d $'\n' "$filename"
```

---

Error handling is a separate topic. See (in Bash) `help test`, especially `test -e` or `test -f`; also `help [`. A basic test may be:

```
[ -f "$filename" ] || exit 1
```

before `nl …`.

Comment: I've updated the script with "$filename". Although the errors are gone, now I'm getting the output like this : 1-dThis is first line.
 2-dThis is second line.
 3-dThis is third line.       Can you explain more on this?

Comment: @saurabh Because your `-d` is not an option. What option-argument do you want for `-s`? It's `-d` in your original code.

Comment: I read it from somewhere that nl treats lines that contain a sequence of 1, 2 or 3 \: strings specially. Use -d $'\n' to avoid that.

Comment: @saurabh See the updated answer.

Comment: and without using -d I'm getting count and text in different lines in the standard output.

Comment: This solves my problem, great detailed answer.